# I can't able to install app-debug.apk into my phone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, adb

I used `cordova version@6` with `JDK 1.8` or greater but there are still I'm able to run an app on my android mobile

I try to `run ionic Cordova run android` 
and so try to remove and reinstall the ionic Cordova platform android

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 18.416 secs
Built the following apk(s):
        E:/Aproject/Project file/thenationaltv app/mynationaltv/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
No hardare devices found, attempting emulator...
Selected emulator HKE839LB
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Aproject\Project file\thenationaltv app\mynationaltv\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

        native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-d... exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Delete the android folder present in platform directory.**

1. ionic cordova platform add android
2. ionic cordova build android

then run

> ionic cordova run android --no-native-run

Comment: @Anand_5050 can you send your log and ionic version

Comment: Able to solve this issue by updating ionic version to latest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled development mode on your device? Otherwise you won't be able to setup an adb connection or install APK's outside the play store.

The exact steps to enable the development mode might slightly differ between brands, but narrows down something like this:

- Go to Settings
- Go to About this phone
- Find the Androir build number, and tap on it seven times
- You'll see a confirmation that development mode is enabled

Sometimes you also need to go into developer settings and enable "Install APK outside the appstore" and "Enable USB Debugging".

Comment: Yes, I already did it
check this error once
this error shows all the time - native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk No hardare devices found, attempting emulator... Selected emulator HKE839LB Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Aproject\Project file\thenationaltv app\mynationaltv\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk' [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

Comment: Well, it's looking for a emulator. If a device is connected, the default is that it should deploy to the device. If no device is found, it reverts to emulator. (Which probably isn't installed, regarding the error log)